# logstash retrying failed action with response code: 429

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

## ES：

node1 -node10 .    10 machines

cpu: 32 core

jvm: 60G

## logstash：

logstash-node1 , logstash-node2

cpu:32 core

jvm 20G

4 logstsh app in every machine

datasource: 18w/s-20w/s

dataformat ：

```
    "index" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 8, 
        "number_of_replicas" : 0,
        "refresh_interval" : "30s"
    }

      "filed1" : {
              "type": "integer"
      },
      "filed2" : {
              "type": "integer"
      },
      "filed3" : {
              "type": "long"
      },
      "filed4" : { 
              "type": "text"
      },
      "filed5":{
        "type": "text"
      },
      "filed6":
      {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "fild7":{
        "type": "date"
      },
      "field8":{
        "type": "geo_point"
      }
    }
```

### logstash.yml

//This defaults to the number of the host's CPU cores.

pipeline.workers: 20

//How many workers should be used per output plugin instance

pipeline.output.workers: 20

//How many events to retrieve from inputs before sending to filters+workers
 pipeline.batch.size: 9000

### logstash kafka.conf

```
input{

   kafka {
        codec => "json"
        topics => ["mytopic"]
        bootstrap_servers =>  "kafka1:9092,kafka2:9092,kafka3:9092,kafka4:9092,kafka5:9092,kafka6:9092,kafka7:9092,kafka8:9092,kafka9:9092,
        kafka11:9092,kafka12:9092,kafka13:9092,kafka14:9092,kafka15:9092,kafka16:9092,kafka17:9092,kafka18:9092,
        kafka19:9092"
        client_id => "kafka"
        auto_offset_reset => "latest"
        group_id => "wzfw510_3"
        consumer_threads => 20
        auto_commit_interval_ms => 500
    }
}

output{
    elasticsearch{
        #codec => rubydebug
        hosts  => ["node1:8200","node2:8200","node3:8200","node4:8200","node5:8200","
node6:8200","node7:8200","node8:8200","node9:8200","node10:8200"]
        index => "myindex"
        document_type => "mytype"
        flush_size => 8000
        #idle_flush_time => 1

   }
}
```

## Q:

Now the speed is 800w-900w/min

the speed is slow ,

and logstash always output error :

```
[2017-05-11T09:27:57,327][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] retrying failed action with response code: 429 ({"type"=>"es_rejected_execution_exception", "reason"=>"rejected execution of org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$7@2393d3d9 on EsThreadPoolExecutor[bulk, queue capacity = 50, org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsThreadPoolExecutor@63898a2e[Running, pool size = 32, active threads = 32, queued tasks = 50, completed tasks = 27163960]]"})
```

How to improve the logstash speed . thks.

Comment: es  version ：5.2                                                                                           logstash version :5.2

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-retrying-failed-action-with-response-code-429/102824